# Can you use Polaris in a Shopify App Extension?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I am building a Shopify post-purchase extension. I would like to use Polaris but it does not seem supported.

For example the following code yeilds this error:

```
return (
    <AppProvider>
        <Page title='test'></Page>
    </AppProvider>
  );
```

```
ExtensionSandboxPostPurchase.latest.en.60c73383f0f7ed657108.worker.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unsupported component: h1
```

Is it possible to use Polaris in an app extension?

Comment: App Extensions use Javascript. If you felt it prudent to load the entire ReactJS and Polaris world into your App Extension, and you wrote JS to load and work, then why not. Nothing like using the atom bomb to kill a few fruitflies!

Comment: @DavidLazar I'm not sure I understand, React is used for extensions https://shopify.dev/apps/checkout/post-purchase/update-an-order-for-a-checkout-post-purchase-app-extension